# SetText by Database Column Value

Tags: android

i have a db named: "dbtest.db" , a table named: "mensagens" , a column named: "usuarioorigem".
in my XML file i have a textview and a button, when button is clicked i want to the value of textview change to the value in the column: "usuarioorigem" .

How do i do it? and can you explain how it works.

i have this code but it doesnt work.

```
            TextView mostrar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUSUARIO);
            mostrar.setText(usuarioorigem.valueOf(returning));
```

Comment: You are asking for someone to explain rather large concepts of SQLite and Android... "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." (From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)) However there are a lot of tutorials online already. Here's one: [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: ok thanks, i will have a look.

Comment: "i just want to know how to get the value of a column in my database and change it in the textview i have in my layout" Ok, what are your get() or fetch() methods from your database adapter?

Comment: im a beginner i dont know what this is

Comment: You need similar methods from the "Reading Row(s)" section in the tutorial I posted. If `getUsuarioorigem(int id)` returns a String then you are all set!

Comment: Just to point you out that you might also want to specify the row whose data you would want to show.

Comment: ok i will keep reading the tutorial. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a **`cursor c`** to point to your database.

```
mostrar.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Database.columns[0]))); // assuming that you want to retrieve the value stored in your first column.
```

The [sample](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) given in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) is a great way to learn cursors.

Comment: and Database gives erros like create a new class ...

Comment: You need to make a file called Database.java which will take care of all the database handling. The cursor is going to point to that database. There are various in-built functions that you can call on cursors too. I would suggest that you go through some tutorial to get a clear idea.

Comment: I added two links in my answer. I am sure they would be helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, There are methods like insert, update available for your respective requirements use them, Follow this tutorial best suited for ur question.

[Android SQLite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and might be suited better as a comment.

Comment: this are all about SQLite tutorial, i dont need it all i just want to know how to get the value of a column in my database and change it in the textview i have in my layout.

Comment: U need to learn sqlite in  for that. If u knows basics of it, u could have done that it requires few lines of code..